# How does 'weight' make an element fill available space in an Android layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

*This is my very first attempt at an Android app. Please forgive all ignorance and folly.*

I get how `weight` works if you assign all your elements a value for that attribute. Then how does `weight` cause a `ListView` to fill all available space between two elements in a `LinearLayout`, when it is the only element that has a weight?

I have a simple layout with a `ListView` at the top, and at the bottom of the screen, an `EditText`, 'Button`, and`TextView`. Only the`ListView`and`TextView`have`weight` attributes (many attributes like side margins etc. and elements with only default attributes omitted for brevity):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:weightSum="10">

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/files_list"
            android:background="@drawable/text_view_border"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="7.99"
            ...
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/result_text"
            ...
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.43"
            android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now how does that make the `ListView` fill the available space on the scree? I would have thought `height=*` or something like that would do it. And the "0.43" + "7.99" not being very near the `weightsome="10"` only adds to my confusion.

Comment: James answer should work fine. Exactly how/why it works I stopped asking myself sometime ago and just accept that the Android framework is very weird sometimes. On the LinearLayout case I know there's some weird inversion of values on the weight when using "0dp" or "wrap_content". As a general rule I've use either weight with 0dp or wrap_content without weight, cause mixing those leads to weirdnessess.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use `weightSum` in this instance.  `weightSum` is more useful if you want a view to take up only part of the available space and not all of it.  If you remove the weight from `result_text` and remove the `weightSum` from the `LinearLayout`, then it will work as intended.  You can also set the `layout_weight` of `files_list` to a nicer number like `1`.

From the [Documenation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:weightSum):

> Defines the maximum weight sum. If unspecified, the sum is computed by
>   adding the layout_weight of all of the children. This can be used for
>   instance to give a single child 50% of the total available space by
>   giving it a layout_weight of 0.5 and setting the weightSum to 1.0.
>
> Must be a floating point value, such as "1.2".

This should do it:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/files_list"
            android:background="@drawable/text_view_border"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            ...
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/result_text"
            ...
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try your example, but the reason behind this question is "why does `weight` work to do this", not, "what alternative is there to `weight`, when semantically it is a little confusing.

Comment: The answer is that's not the purpose of weight.  You want the `ListView` to take up all available space so weight is not needed.  This is not an alternative to weight; weight is the wrong solution.

Comment: My app with the wrong solution was working on a Nexus emulator and my phone. I copied the weight example form an answer here on SO, and suddenly my app worked. What does make the `LisrView` take all the remaining space then? Is it just because it has an overflow and can't cover other controls, so if it only had 1 element, it would not fill all the space?

Comment: The space `ListView` takes up follows the same rules as other views.  It will only grow with it's children if you use `wrap_content` which is not encouraged.  If it only had 1 child and it's height was set to `match_parent` or 0 height + weight, the `ListView` will take up all the space and the child will only take up the needed space inside the `ListView` (as you would expect).

Comment: Thank you for all the explaining, James.

Answer (score 0):

use with android:layout_width="match_parent" insted of fill_parent.
this will fill all the space of the screen of width.
in the last version of android the fill_parent is no longer used

Comment: I don't want to fill the screen width. I have `android:orientation="vertical"` and I have elements at the bottom of the screen, and I want the `ListView` to fill the space remaining between top-of-screen and the topmost bottom element.